# sharepoint 2013 and reporting add in 2016 no render correctly

Tags: 2013, 2016, reporting-services, reports, report-viewer

I have a server with Sharepoint 2013 installed and I have installed reporting services - Sharepoint 2016 and the reporting services complement for SharePoint products, and successfully configured the reporting services in SharePoint 2013, but when I open a report it does not render it correctly, there are Some problem of incompatibility with SharePoint 2013 and the add-in of SQL server 2016 for SharePoint?

[image: Installer]

[image: Renderized report in sharepoint2013]

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2016 Reporting Services supports integration with SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint 2016. but you should make sure that you have installed [Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Reporting Services Add-in for Microsoft SharePoint (rsSharePoint.msi)](https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=52682) on the SharePoint servers.

For more details check [Supported Combinations of SharePoint and Reporting Services Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/supported-combinations-of-sharepoint-and-reporting-services-server)